# How can I get bluetooth speakers to work with pulseaudio in NixOS?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, nixos

I've managed to get my bluetooth speakers to connect, but Pulseaudio apparently doesn't recognize them as an audio device. Following advice on the NixOS Wiki, I now have this in my configuration.nix:

```
  sound.enable = true;
  hardware = {
    pulseaudio = {
      enable = true;
      package = pkgs.pulseaudioFull;
      extraModules = [ pkgs.pulseaudio-modules-bt ];
    };
    bluetooth = {
      enable = true;
      extraConfig = "
        [General]
        Enable=Source,Sink,Media,Socket
      ";
    };
  };
```

Do I need anything else?

The errors I'm seeing in `journalctl` are these:

```
Nov 17 23:33:45 jon-laptop pulseaudio[4563]: E: [pulseaudio] bluez4-util.c: org.bluez.Manager.GetProperties() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetProperties" with signature "" on interface "org.bluez.Manager" doesn't exist
Nov 17 23:33:45 jon-laptop pulseaudio[4563]: E: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
```

Comment: Have you paired the Bluetooth device with NixOS?

Comment: Yep. As I say above, I've managed to connect to the speakers already (which first requires pairing them). The speakers just aren't detected as an audio device.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work by first connecting the device (bluethoothctl), then restarting pulseaudio `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio`.

And then finally set the audio device to `A2DP` for better quality with pavucontrol.